# FOSUserBundle + login_check

Tags: security, authentication, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have followed the manual and created MyBundle which extends FOSUserBundle,

Everything works ok so far, I can

1)register a user 
2)send him email
3)confirmed his account (after confirmation I am logged in)
4)logout

but afterwords I ***cannot login***. 
The user is enabled in the database.

A query is fired but the login form error is "Bad credentials...".

I am using , in security.yml

`encoders:
        'FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface': sha512`

so my password field inside the database uses both sha512 encryption + salt.

Should I change my extended user in any way to use 512 encoder and salt when comparing the db password and the one the user provided?

If this is the problem ,
does anyone know in which class and how to implement the above because this

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password

does not help me right now.

Or can anyone guide me on how to debug this?

Lastly I really stuck on this...

Answer (score 0):

Check your database that contains the users you had created. Then check that in your user tale in Db column name `enable=1` for any user. The registered user can login only if `enable=1`.If `enable=0`,your could'nt login.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: the user is enabled in the database

Answer (score 0):

FOSUserbundle for expects the fields "_password" and "_username" everything else will not work if you didn't customize these fieldnames. (?)- cleaned your cache ?

But maybe its a real problem. Then you maybe should post some code.